# How to run USSD code in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, ussd

i am using dual sim phone. Now i want to run USSD code by one particular network without selecting the operator to call.

my code:

```
 String ussdCode = "*" + "123" + Uri.encode("#");
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
```

Response: now it was asking me to select the operator to call the ussd code. I want to run that USSD Code by that particular operator  without asking.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: USSD is not supported in Android.  There is no API to make a USSD call.

Comment: @GabeSechan : the code he shares exactly fire an intent to make a ussd call ! what do you mean by not supporting that?

Comment: @Arash THere is no built in way to make a USSD via an API.  You can't choose what SIM does it, you can't get a result.  There's no promise that the dialer app will actually support USSD or make a USSD request, or show any result if it does, or support all USSD features.  Basically you have something that will maybe kinda sorta work on some phones.

Answer (score 1):

With Samsung devices use the below

```
callIntent.putExtra("simSlot", simSlot);
```

where simSlot is integer as 0,1